# Why master deferred in not being rejected early in $.when as soon as one of the Deferreds is rejected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred

According to http://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/ `$.when()` should **reject the master Deferred as soon as one of the Deferreds is rejected**. Why do I get all 4 console.log messages, before 'caught OnPreRenderFailed' message.
My understanding is that as soon as second deferred is rejected I should not get `console.log('third deferred');` and `console.log('fourth deferred');` or get them after `console.log('caught OnPreRenderFailed');`
Unless I am super lucky(or not) to get methods fire in (1,3,4,2) sequence all the time. I must be missing something here.
 [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e7k8T/)

```
 $(document).on('OnPreRenderResolved', function () {
       console.log('caught OnPreRenderResolved');
   });
   $(document).on('OnPreRenderFailed', function () {
       console.log('caught OnPreRenderFailed');
   })
    $(document).on('OnPreRender', function (e, options) {
       console.log('OnPreRender fired');
       options.callback();
   });
   $(document).trigger('OnPreRender', {
       callback: function () {
           $.when.apply($, [$.Deferred(function (deferred) {
               console.log('first deferred');
               deferred.resolve();
           }), $.Deferred(function (deferred) {
               console.log('second deferred');
               deferred.reject();
           }), $.Deferred(function (deferred) {
               console.log('third deferred');
               deferred.resolve();
           }), $.Deferred(function (deferred) {
               console.log('fourth deferred');
               deferred.resolve();
           })]).then(function () {
               $(document).trigger("OnPreRenderResolved");
           }, function () {
               $(document).trigger("OnPreRenderFailed");
           })
       }
   });
```

Comment: You are getting 4 logs, because you fire 4 functions parallely. Simple as that. Now the question is: what are you trying to achieve? Generally jobs in `$.when` should be independent. What you are saying is that they should depend on whether other are successful or not. If so then you should not use `$.when` but chain them instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing is that evaluation is always synchronous. You cannot force anything in between. So in order to do that you have to force your functions into being asynchronous. You can achieve this by using `setTimeout(..., 0);`:

```
$.when.apply($, [
    $.Deferred(function (deferred) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log('first deferred');
            deferred.resolve();
        }, 0);
    }),
    $.Deferred(function (deferred) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log('second deferred');
            deferred.resolve();
        }, 0);
    }),
    ...
]);
```

Don't ever use `$.when` with synchronous code. That's simply pointless.

Note however that the order of setTimeout's is not defined. You may end up with strange results.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/e7k8T/4/ that shows `console.log('caught OnPreRenderFailed')` fired before `console.log('third deferred');` and `console.log('fourth deferred');` this was eye opener to me.

Answer (score 1):

It's happening simply because the JS interpreter has to evaluate the parameters passed to `$.when` before it can actually call `$.when`.

Since the calls to `$.Deferred` are all inline parameters, they'll all complete (outputting their `console.log` messages) but only once they're all complete will `$.when` proceed, at which point it'll then determine that one of the promises was rejected.

It's as if you've written:

```
f(a(), b(), c(), d());
```

Each of `a` ... `d` have to return before `f` ever gets called.

Furthermore, since none of your functions initiate any asynchronous actions, there's absolutely no chance of the console output from those functions appearing *after* the call to `$.when`.

Comment: Can you think of the way to reorganise the code so that `b()` (or any) being rejected would terminate the process?

Comment: @LIUFA sure - just don't write them inline.  Created your four deferred objects first, and just pass the results of them to `$.when`.   You'll still see the log messages, though.  Or are you saying that you don't want e.g. the third process to even start if the second failed?

Comment: That's not true. First of all: you can't stop these processes. Also from docs: "The method will resolve its master Deferred as soon as all the Deferreds resolve, or reject the master Deferred as soon as one of the Deferreds is rejected." so it won't wait until all of them finish (unless the code is synchronous which is in this case).

Comment: @freakish I think you've misunderstood.  `$.when` can't even _start_ considering what to do until its parameters have been evaluated.  That's how function parameters work.

Comment: @LIUFA That's what I meant if you just want the normal behaviour.  If you don't want `c` to start until `b` is resolved you'd have to chain them serially instead.

Comment: @Alnitak Yes, but what if we change the code and wrap logs with `setTimeout`? The result will still be the same even though the evaluation will be deferred. And `$.when` won't wait until all of them finish their jobs. Also using `$.when` with synchronous functions is pretty much pointless.

Comment: @freakish yup, it's a poor use case.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/e7k8T/3/ How do I need to construct the code so that **reject the master Deferred as soon as one of the Deferreds is rejected** would happen?

Comment: @LIUFA You have to force the code to be asynchronous. One way would be to use `setTimeout(..., 0);`: http://jsfiddle.net/e7k8T/4/ One more time: **don't use $.when with synchronous functions, never ever**. It's simply pointless.

Comment: @LIUFA the code construction you have is fine, _so long as you don't expect the third and fourth promise to somehow get aborted_ when the second is rejected.  Promises don't work like that.  The master deferred is still rejected, but all of the other functions still have to complete.

Comment: @LIUFA FWIW, I think you need to explain more what you're trying to achieve, rather than get a fix for this perceived problem.

Comment: @freakish could you post it as an answer please, this is what I was failing to understand. Thank you.

Comment: @Alnitak absolutely but reject fires before 3 and 4 is being evaluated and this is what I was looking for (or rather missing from `$.when`).

Answer (score 0):

not quite, when is still rejected but the other async process are not stopped, what when does is report the rejection as soon as the first one fails to resolve. the only library i have seen that is able to cancel promises is bluebird